# Buffer I/O error on device sdb

Tags: linux, usb

When I connect my mobile phone (brand Huawei) on my USB port on Linux I get next error messages from `dmesg`:

```
[45771.099208] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 33
[45771.099212] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 33
[45771.099222] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 0
[45771.099225] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 0
[45771.099232] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 2
[45771.099236] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 2
[45771.099240] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 0
[45771.099243] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 0
[45771.099250] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 0
[45771.099257] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 512
```

If I connect my phone while I'm running Windows, then everything works properly. I must notice that I had same problem before, and suddenly it just started to work. But I reinstalled Linux and now I have problem. Does anyone know if there is some driver problem or what?